# I have an ASP.NET MVC controller that needs to call a bootstrap dialogue, and I've hit a wall

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Just starting out and I'm stuck.

On form submit my controller does its model checks and can call a view that displays an error message if needed. This then requires the user to hit back to return to the Data entry page.

I would like to make it much cleaner and popup a boot strap modal with the error message, this would then not interrupt the users work flow.  They can then click Ok and reenter the Data.

```
if (LocExists(obj.Loc.BName, obj.Loc.LocTId.ToString()) == true) 
{
    obj.Loc.BName = null;
    obj.Loc.LocTId= 0;

    return View("ShowError");
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this task ?

Many thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I render a partial view error modal into another view from a MVC controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60673732/how-can-i-render-a-partial-view-error-modal-into-another-view-from-a-mvc-control)

Answer (score 0):

You could have a default endpoint and a validation endpoint that will point to the same View like so

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //This is the default that will lead to your Form View
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {             
            return View();
        }

        //This is the validation endpoint that will check for the Model state.
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(CustomModel yourmodel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               ViewBag.Error = "There is an error in the form";
               return View();
            }
            //Proceed with your form action etc etc
            //...
            //...
            return View();
        }
    }
```

And in your View you could check if there's a Error ViewBag

```
@if (!Object.Equals(ViewBag.Error, null))
{
    <div class="alert alert-warning mt-10" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    <span>There is an error with your data check again.</span>
    </div>
}
```

Also since you use Bootstrap you could use Bootstrap's validation (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/)